# After update to ChromeDriver 113 for Windows 10, PC is still starting version 108

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

When I start chromeDriver 113, I still get the 108 version.

I cleared the cache different times
I Installed the latest Chrome browser
I deleted the 108 chromeDriver
I deleted the folder with the chromeDriver
I restarted windows
I created a new folder with a new name for the 113 driver
I set the Path to the new folder
I started the ChromeDriver with CMD but there is still version 108

Any suggestions?